# Prove that if non-homogeniety of ODE is bounded then its solution is also bounded

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, dynamical-systems

Please let me know if my proof is fine, or if you'd make some modifications.

Consider the general system of ODEs $x'=Ax+b(t)$ **(1)**, $x(0)=x_0$ where all eigenvalues of $A$ have negative real parts and $b(t)$ is continuous for all $t$. Thus we have $\lvert e^{At}\lvert\le Me^{\gamma t}$, where $M>0$, $\gamma < 0$ for $t\geq 0$.

Now, the solution of (1) is $x(t) = e^{At}x_0 + \int\limits_0^t e^{A(t-s)}b(s)ds$, so we have:

$\lvert x(t)\lvert = \lvert e^{At}x_0 + \int\limits_0^t e^{A(t-s)}b(s)ds\lvert\leq \lvert e^{At}\lvert + \lvert \int\limits_0^t e^{A(t-s)}b(s)ds\lvert$.

Let $B = \sup\limits_{0\le s \le t}\lvert b(s) \lvert$. Moreover, since $(t-s) \geq 0$ for $0\le s \le t$, $\lvert e^{A(t-s)}\rvert \le Me^{\gamma s}$ Thus,

$\lvert e^{At}\lvert + \lvert \int\limits_0^t e^{A(t-s)}b(s)ds\lvert$ $\le \lvert e^{At}\lvert + \lvert B\int\limits_0^t e^{A(t-s)}ds\lvert\le \lvert e^{At}\lvert + \lvert B\int\limits_0^t e^{A(t-s)}ds\lvert\le Me^{\gamma t}+B\int\limits_0^t Me^{\gamma s} = Me^{\gamma t}+BM\frac{1}{\gamma}(e^{\gamma t}-1).$
Thus the solution is bounded for all $t\ge 0$.

Comment: Looks good, now prove it for when $A=A(t)$! In general, using something like Grönwall's Inequality will get you the result even when A is a matrix of functions. Kinda cool.

Comment: Notice that the last formula tends to $-BM<0$ when $t\to\infty$. Can you find the mistake in the proof? Hint: look again at $B$.

Comment: @Jonas: I think that $BM\frac{1}{\gamma}(e^{\gamma t}-1)$ should be in absolute value.

Comment: OK, but that's not the main problem: $B$ is the supremum up to $t$, it is impossible to deduce from there that the solution is bounded. Or do you want to prove something else?

Comment: I think I forgot to specify that $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty} b(t) = 0$ is a given. Otherwise, of course, there's no guarantee of convergence.

Comment: Few remarks: 1) you forgot about $\lvert x_0 \rvert$ almost everywhere; 2) you forgot about extra absolute value in integral inequality that you use; 3) if $\| e^{Au} \| \leqslant Me^{\gamma u}$ for $\gamma <0$ and for $u > 0$, it's safe to write that $\| e^{A(t-s)} \| \leqslant Me^{\gamma (t-s)}$ when $t-s \geqslant 0$, but it's not very true to write $\| e^{A(t-s)} \| \leqslant Me^{\gamma s}$; 4) though it's a matter of taste, distinguishing operator norms from vector norms sometimes makes proof easier to read (for example, $\| \cdot \|$ vs $\lvert \cdot \rvert$)

Comment: Also, you don't really need that $\lim\limits_{t \rightarrow \infty} \lvert b(t) \rvert = 0$ to prove boundedness of solutions. In fact you only need this to prove that all solutions tend to zero solution.